# js deleting submitted form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, forms

The problem:
Javascript function( which was premade by template) cleans the form data sent to me by php

The php code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'GJ '
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $phone = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_to = 'email@email.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Телефон: ' . $phone . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body);

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

The javascript function code:

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {'use strict',
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

When there's no js code php returns white screen with a line but the @mail sends normal message, but when there is this code fade in and out works good, but the data arrives empty. The message in message and name is cyrylic if that is important.

Please help me fix it(i.e. i need both data arriving and success fade-in appearing or at least data arriving with no .php white screen) or just explain what the js code does i don't get it.
Thanks

Comment: So you're issue is with Javascript?

Comment: on you php code do `var_dump($_POST)` and then check in the browser's network response tab whats returning.

Comment: yes, no javascript = data sent
javascript= data arrives empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided the `data` argument for `$.post`

Try

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {'use strict',
    var $this = $(this);    
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $this.serialize(), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

References:

[**jQuery.post() Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

**[jQuery.serialize() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! var before $this stop script from working though

Comment: no reason that adding `var` should stop script. Shouldn't declare variables without using `var` or asking for all sorts of problems

Comment: maybe 'use strict' can be the reason, old style programming as far as i've looked it up, it allows not using var but shouldn't prohibit, anyway func without var works good, with var not working.

Comment: ahh it's because of comma after `use strict` , try `;` Use your browser console to check errors. Likely throwing a syntax error there